# How do I remove multiple array elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of elements in Ruby  `[2,4,6,3,8]` I need to remove  array with value, How do I do that?

```
[{x: "69", y: "104"},{x: "69", y: "109"},{x: "69", y: "300"}]
```

example I want remove x 69 and y 109

Comment: `arr.filter(({ x, y }) => x !== '69' && y !== '109')`

Comment: do you want to remove any object with `x === 69` or with `y === 109` or where both conditions are true? please add what you have tried and which result do you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example , use filter (Array prototype method).

```js
 var ARRAY = [{x: "69", y: "104"},{x: "69", y: "109"},{x: "69", y: "300"}]
            .filter(function(item){
  return item.x==="69" && item.y==="109";
     });
 
  
console.log(ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` on the object to filter the object not having those `x` and `y` values:

```js
var arr = [{'x': "69", 'y': "104"},{'x': "69", 'y': "109"},{'x': "69", 'y': "300"}];
var removeX = '69', removeY = '109';

var res = arr.filter((obj)=> (obj.x !== removeX || obj.y !== removeY));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: im already tick your answer but my point under 15 :), but thanks for help

Comment: @Udin see properly, there is a tick mark sign below the arrow votes which you can tick even though you have less that 15 points